# fetch/merge my local branch with a certain remote branch

Tags: git, merge, branch, fetch

Ok so this is what I'm trying to do.

I have a local repo that's tracking a remote repo. Now a particular branch on that remote ('core15') got some changes. Is it possible for me to fetch the changes made to the core15 remote branch and merge them with my local master branch? I believe I've done the fetch/merge no problem in the past but I think that's because the changes normally get pushed to the remotes master branch.

Sorry if that doesn't make sense, I haven't used git all that much. I read through the documentations on syncing branch but couldn't see a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shouldn't you be merging with your local `core15` branch? Normally, your local master branch should track the remote master branch. But I guess people have different git workflows. This is what I would normally advise:

```
git fetch
git checkout core15
git merge origin/core15
```

Your essentially sync merging your core15. Then you would normally do whatever you need to in that branch and then either (1) push it back to the remote repository for a pull request to the master if you have codereview in your workflow  or (2) merge it yourself to the master and then push the master to the remote repository.

But if you really want to merge into your local master branch

```
git fetch
git checkout master
git merge origin/core15
```